# Install and use multiple versions of a module using setup.py?

Tags: python, dpkg

I have a Python program, that I'm packaging into a Debian package. I use the Python module `slackclient==2.5.0` for my own program, but another module `rtmbot` which needs `slackclient==1.3.2`. If I install both modules, I obviously have a conflict in my `setup.py` and only install one of them. How do you handle that? A `virtualenv` within a `virtualenv`? Installing both and namespacing somehow? And if so, how do I do that within the process of building and not manually?

Comment: `rtmbot` requires a `slackclient` version below `2`. I guess it is not compatible with version `2`. It is not possible to install two version of on library at the same time, but of cause you could modify one to be a separate library with its own namespace. If you don't want that, you have to make a choice: `rtmbot` xor `slackclient 2`.

Comment: So I have to build a separate package for `rtmbot`, within which I'm just going to import `rtmbot`? Seems a bit awkward to me.
I know about the version conflicts, that's what I wrote in the question. I may have been a bit too precise with the version numbers. 

Regarding settling for `slackclient>=1, <2`: Among other changes, they completely renamed the methods and I don't want to turn my program into legacy code before it's even deployed.

Comment: Huh, I found out I can side-step that whole issue. Luckily, one change that Slack did in their v2 of `slackclient` was, that they made you import it through `import slack` instead of `import slackclient` as in their v1 version. This means, if I just `pip install rtmbot` it will install the `slackclient` with v1.3.2. Now I can just `pip download slackclient`, rename the `slackclient*.whl` file into `slack*.whl`, install it with `wheel` and be able to use both versions in the same virtual environment. It still feels like a hack, but at least I don't have to weep in dependency hell. Hooray!

Comment: I installed it with `pip install slack*.whl` not directly with wheel btw.

`$ python3 -c "import slackclient; print(slackclient.version.__version__)"` => 1.3.2
`$ python3 -c "import slack; print(slack.version.__version__)"` => 2.5.0